# How to put instead of a list, a dictionary, for concurrency (asynchrony) through the multiprocessing.dummy Pool

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-multiprocessing

I want to run a leap of files, but for this I need a dictionary, since it's easier to chronize, let's say this: `{'first_name': ['first_link', 'second_link']}` and it turns out that Pool takes just the first `key`
, that is, the string , and it turns out that `the values are not available` and an error occurs, how can I send the dictionary there instead of the list of links?

P.S. Can I send several parameters to the Pool?
`results = pool.map (download_file, cat_l_dict, some _dict)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw your dictionary to the list

```
results = pool.map(download_file, [cat_l_dict])
```

after that dict gonna be work like dict